# how to enable hintText of TextField multiline in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Because of [InputDecorator] defaults [maxLines] to 1,  I can't find any way to  enable multiline when hintText sometimes are a little long.

Answer (score 14):

Simply set `hintMaxLines: 2` or however many lines you need in the `InputDecoration` option.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintMaxLines: 2
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, working great on multiline textfield: ` TextField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintMaxLines: 3,
            hintText:
                'My veeeeeeeeeeeeeeery veeeeeery large hint text'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: null,
      )`

Answer (score -1):

In Flutter, Textfield has hintText open.

```
 new TextFormField(
          controller: inputBoxController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: inputBoxName,
            hintText: inputBoxName,
          ),
          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? msg : null,
          onSaved: (val) => val,
        ),
```